# Select elements with empty spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button when clicked it hides all table rows with empty td elements however when my page renders I get some td elements that when I open them in firebug look like this:

[image]

How can I select fields that have these invisible spaces in them ? For some reason  tag acts like a block element example:

```
<b></b> Will produce as is
```

However

```
    <b>    
........// This happens because I have if/else statements  
........@if($value == '')..
........@endif..
....</b>
```

All the ... turn into white space.

Won't turn to `<b></b>` as one would expect same. Can I fix this with CSS or is there a way to select these fields with jQuery.

`element:empty` wont work.

Comment: How do you generate your HTML markup?

Comment: If you don't want the white-space in the HTML why are you (deliberately?) leaving white-space in the HTML? If you remove it from the HTML it won't be present in the DOM, and then `:empty` will work (in compliant browsers, obviously).

Comment: Remove newlines and spaces from your HTML source. Or run it via a minifier before deployment.

Comment: @DavidThomas   
It's a bade.php documment I have if() else endif statements in between that b tag. So i end up getting all those whitespaces.

Comment: Then while I think I, or we, have answered this question it might be worth asking another question as regards tidying up your PHP's `if` / `else`, and how to use it without creating surplus white-space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select `<td>` elements whose text is simply white-space:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim().length === 0;
// obviously the CSS call is simply an example of chaining, adjust as appropriate
}).css('background-color','#ffa');
```

I would, however, suggest removing the extraneous - and apparently unwanted - white-space from the HTML at the point of its creation, which would allow you to simply use:

```
$('td:empty').css('background-color','#ffa');
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:empty` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use smth like this:

```
$('div,span,b,p').each(function() { //here you can specify necessary tags
         if (jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == "") {
                   //Do Something
         }
});
```

Comment: `*` is an extremely costly selector... perhaps it would be useful to utilize a more specific selector.

Comment: @Terry, agree with you. Please, see my updated answer.